# In VSCode, how to display c++ comments starting with "//!" in different colors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

In CLion, comments starting with "//!" are green, while comments starting with "//" are gray

In vscode, both comments are green

How to use different colors to distinguish these two kinds of comments in vscode?

PS: I cannot attach screenshots of clion and vscode because I don't have enough reputations. Here is a sample code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  // in clion, this line is grey; in vscode it is green
  //! in clion and vscode, this line is green
  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I googled keywords `vscode c++ comment "//!"` and `vscode different comment in different colors`, but found no useful information

Comment: Have you read e.g. [this **syntax highlight** guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)?

Comment: use the extension **Highlight**

Comment: [Injection grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars) is the relevant section in the above linked documentation.

Comment: if you want syntax highlighting color it different it must have a different TextMate Scope, not very likely that Microsoft C++ extension has a TextMate rule for `//!`, and the theme must have a color assigned to this different type of comment scope, so it will not work with syntax highlighting